# How can I change the axios date format in @nuxtjs/axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using `@nuxtjs/axios` in my `nuxt.js` project. I'm fetching a content_type from my API, but axios formats the date into a `ISO 8601` format. Is there any way you can modify this in the nuxt.config.js?

like:

```
axios: {
 data: 'yyyy/dd/mm'
}
```

any solution?

> I don't want to use the moment library

Comment: I think you can’t change the date format, since this is a string generated by the server. You can use the middleware to convert the data format during processing.

Comment: "I dont want to use the moment library" I mean, that's up to you, but it's considered the gold standard in JS date work for a reason. Axios isn't doing anything here beyond converting the Date object into a string. Have you considered fixing your API to use the ISO 8601 standard instead of a non-standard date format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not about Axios. Axios is just using `JSON.stringify` on a request object and `JSON.stringify` converts dates into ISO 8601 format. If you want different format, don't pass a Date - format it yourself and pass a string to Axios instead of Date

Basic Date formatting [is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803/381282), [you don't need Moment.js](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs). For more advanced formating, `date-fns` is much better/smaller (with support for tree-shaking)

```js
myDateFormat = function(d) {
  return d.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
}

var d1 = new Date(Date.now())

console.log(d1)
console.log(myDateFormat(d1))
```

Also consider changing your API to use more standard date format....